# No sound from AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I'm trying to add loop music to my app. The simulator runs, but there's no music coming out.

```
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

  func startAudio() {
    let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "backsong", ofType: "mp3")
    let fileURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath!)
    do {
        audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: fileURL, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
        audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayer.volume = 1
    } catch {
        self.present(UIAlertController.init(title: "Error", message: "Error Message", preferredStyle: .alert), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    audioPlayer.play()
  }
}
```

Comment: Not really sure, my goal is to add a music that loops and play in every sector of my views/page in the app. I ran the app, the simulator ran without any debugging issue. Only the music is not coming out.

Comment: The code as shown never calls `startAudio()`. Make sure you actually do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never called the function, so the lines of codes within the function aren't being called. Call the function `startAudio()` in viewDidLoad().